# Homebrew gets timeouts from github.com

Tags: macos, timeout, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, homebrew-cask

Each time I run `brew update` I get timeouts for several URLs. It is a different set of URLs everytime I run the command. But accessing the URLs in my web browser is fast and I experience no problems. Here is Homebrew's output:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to update tap: caskroom/cask
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-fonts/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to update tap: caskroom/fonts
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/dupes
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/php
Already up-to-date.
```

Is there anything I can do about this, like increasing a timeout-time? I didn't find anything on the man page.

**Edit**

In the meantime I learned that my internet provider merged with another company. Now they're having some troubles because suddenly a lot more people use the same network. I tried `brew update` while connected to the university's wifi and didn't have any troubles there. So I guess for updating from home I'd need some way to increase the timeout limit or to automatically retry the individual request to the respective failed github repo a couple of times before issuing an error something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same thing after upgrading to El Capitan. First I tried brew update, getting a permission denied. After using sudo (my bad :)), it generated some git files owned by root.

Now you get the timeout.

```
      sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Afterwards

```
      brew update
```

works again.

Comment: nope, sorry. that didn't help me with the timeouts. but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I got same plobrem under proxy. The problem was resolved by setting the proxy.

Set proxy: Without username and password

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.com:port
git config --global https.proxy http://proxy.com:port
```

Set Proxy: With username and password

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy.com:port
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxy.com:port
```

If it were not for effect, reset them.

```
git config --global http.proxy ''
git config --global https.proxy ''
```

Comment: that's interesting to know, but sadly not the solution for me, since i don't have a proxy.

Comment: My mind is asking me why I need proxy